# Import range from Google Spreadsheet Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

The code I have is importing everything on a Google Spreadsheet including row number and column header.

How do I import a certain range of the sheet?

```
Sub Basic_Web_Query()
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
  "URL;https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11H_-UFOpNAtQbs5BNOwZZK1KBew6l-8XKmoMycWuizU/edit?usp=sharing", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
  .Name = "q?s=goog_2"
  .FieldNames = False
  .RowNumbers = False
  .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
  .PreserveFormatting = True
  .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
  .BackgroundQuery = True
  .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
  .SavePassword = False
  .SaveData = True
  .AdjustColumnWidth = True
  .RefreshPeriod = 0
  .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
  .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
  .WebTables = "1"
  .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = False
  .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
  .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
  .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
  .WebDisableRedirections = False
  .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```